# Splitting a REST response to separate fields in groovy and soapUI

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I am working on a test suite in SoapUI that contain both REST and SOAP requests.
The scenario begins with a REST request. From the response I need to take the user name value.
The response is the following:

```
{
   "user_name": "Z.ZCLGN",
   "first_name": "Tester1",
   "user_code": "19225",
   "last_name": "QA"
}
```

I need the "Z.ZCLGN". How do I split the username value so I could transfer it to the next Soap Request? should I use split like I'm trying to do and if so how?

Thats what I have so far in a groovy script:

```
def responseAsXml = context.expand( '${GetToken#ResponseAsXml#declare namespace ns1=\'https://10.1.9.13/cvbs/oauth2/token\'; //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:user[1]}' )
log.info responseAsXml
def (user_name, first_name, Tester1, user_code, last_name) = responseAsXml.split("")
```

Comment: It seems that You just need to parse the response and get the value You're interested in.

Comment: ok, how do I do it? never parsed yet and could not figure it out from the things I saw while googling.

Comment: It seems that @Renato has already answered Your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Groovy scripting for that.
Use Property Transfer.

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html

But if you love scripting so much you still want to do it, here you go:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
def userName = json.user_name
// now use userName in some other request by setting a property, for exampl
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "MyProp", userName )
```

More help about Json parsing here:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2011/04/groovy-goodness-parse-json-with.html

But I would also recommend reading the tips for SoapUI beginners:

http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/10-tips-for-the-soapui-beginner.html

Comment: Well by transferring a property all the fields are transferred and I need only one of them. As shown above the user info is {
   "user_name": "Z.ZCLGN",
   "first_name": "Tester1",
   "user_code": "19225",
   "last_name": "QA"
}

Comment: if you have a solution for that please do share. For now the script is working. Thanks very much!

Comment: In the latest version of SoapUI Pro, you can use JSONPath in the property transfer. When creating the property transfer, you can select "Source" (the request test step), "Property" (Response), and Path language (JSONPath), which looks like ``${REST Test Request#Response#$.user_name}``. You can then use the same thing to determine the property transfer Target. In older versions of SoapUI, you may have to use ResponseAsXML and then XPath (SoapUI Pro creates it for you automatically) instead of JSONPath.